# Undirected graph using Raphael layouted using Jointjs

Tags: layout, d3.js, graph, raphael, jointjs

I am trying to create an undirected graph in Raphael (unsuccessful till now) and layout it using JointJs. I am able to create an undirected graph in JointJs and layout it. 

From past couple of days i have been going through Raphael documentation, did a local setup but struggling to create a graph. **My basic requirement is diagramming/graph creation through Raphael and rendering it with proper layout(like in jointjs; DirectedGraph Layout). Now, this auto layout is not supported by Raphael so, i have to use an external library only for layout purpose.**

Now, as far as i've worked with JointJs, it does a acceptable job but even though ***lets say i've graph from raphael, still not sure how will i use it with DirectedGraph Layout***.

D3 was also an option but after i explored it, i could not get much about layouting. Not necessarily i should use JointJs but could be another library which can support my use case.

My main concerns are:

1. How to draw undirected graph in Rapahel.
2. How to consume the graph drawn in Raphael in JointJs (or any layouting library)
                                          
    OR 
   Layout technique/library that would do both diagramming and layout like in image from link below.
   http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=10320373554237333472

Any resources/code snippet will be helpful.
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: d3 has a [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout). It can do [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

Comment: D3 has force layout but i have to use Directed Graph Layout or something like it.

Comment: How does that make a difference? Force layout lets you specify zero, 1 or 2 (or more links) between any two nodes. That should allow you to build any kind of graph. No?

Comment: It's actually a huge difference. Force-directed layout (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing) is suitable for different kinds of problems than Layered Graph drawing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing).

Comment: If it wouldn't have made a difference, i could have implemented Force Layout and used D3 for diagramming too. But like Dave mentioned there is huge difference. Also as i mentioned in question i need anything which can give me as in image (browse from the link), which is not possible by Force layout!